# Can I say the Amidah out loud if it helps my kavanah?

Tags: halacha, minhag, tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, tzibur-community

If I am davening at home and it would not be disruptive to others, is there any reason I might be permitted to say the Amidah out loud--for example, if it helped me with my concentration or orientation to G-d?

I found a discussion on the second half of the page [here](http://rabbi.bendory.com/audio/amidah/amidah10.php), which includes mention of the original Mishnaic source that one should daven the Amidah silently. However, this discussion seems to have some problems; it was hard for me to pick up a normative conclusion (other than the guy's opinion) from it. Also, I would like to know if one could pronounce the Amidah in a relatively normal speaking voice, which is not addressed.

My instinct is that doing so is not prohibited at the strictest levels, since some kiruv minyanim daven the Amidah out loud.